# Convert string to function name in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have many functions with the same prefix. I want to use a combination of strings to invoke the function.

```
def func_plus_one(v):
    return v+1

def func_plus_two(v):
    return v+2

a='plus_one'
b='plus_two'
```

So how can I use `'func_'+a` and `'func_'+b` to use the function?

Comment: You probably shouldn't do that.

Comment: Why not use `a = func_plus_one` and skip the strings part?

Comment: because 'plus_one', 'plus_two' are also used for other purposes

Comment: @superb rain ... dynamic lookup of things to call is a perfectly acceptable thing to be doing

Comment: `for i,n in enumerate(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']): exec(f'def func_plus_{n}(v): return {v}+i')`

Comment: @donkopotamus You don't think there's probably a better way to do what they're actually trying to do?

Comment: @superb rain ... we don’t know, as we don’t know if `a` is a dynamic variable ... but dynamic resolution of callables based on variables is a pretty common problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the functions are in the same module as the code needing to reference them, use the `globals()` of the module.  You could call the function indicated by `a` using:

```
globals()['func_' + a](x)
```

If they are in another module, use `getattr`

```
getattr(some_module, func_' + a)(x)
```